# Why is this length $r d\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, electromagnetism

I am trying to find the magnetic field due to a current carrying wire.

[image: diagram]

Why is the length $rd\theta$? One of the radius is $r$ but the other is $(r+dL \cos(\theta))$. And, $\theta$ can be large or small. How do you assume that the two lengths are $r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $r \theta$ is the length of the arc of the circle of radius r subtended by a central angle $\theta$. This comes straight from the [definition of radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Definition).

In the picture, it seems they are approximating the "straight" leg of the little triangle, with the "curved" arc swept out by the arm of length $r$ through angle $d\theta$. This is reasonable when $d\theta$ is small.

Comment: theta does not have to be small. It can be large also depending on which location you consider

Comment: typo, fixed it.